# Is 'suspected' a verb and "had been an arrangement....." noun complement of marriage in this sentence?

Tags: verbs

> In the end, most people suspected the marriage had been an arrangement of sorts between Ali and Sanubar.
>   -(The Kite Runner)

Is 'suspected' a verb and "had been an arrangement....." noun complement of marriage?

Answer (score 1):

> *In the end,* [*most people suspected (that) the marriage had been an arrangement*
>   *of sorts between Ali and Sanubar*].

Your analysis is right, except that the declarative content clause (your noun clause) is "the marriage had been an arrangement of sorts between Ali and Sanubar". The content clause is complement of "suspected".

Note that the subordinator "that" can be optionally added, as shown.

Comment: Thankyou so much Sir. I usually get confused when I see too many verbs in a single sentence.